# How to know user accounts available on LAN computer?

Tags: local-area-network, user-accounts, windows

I would like to find out a list of user accounts on a remote Windows PC. I would like to do this from the windows command prompt. Is this possible and if so how ?

Original
Can we get available Users under windows through one computer for other computer and both are in LAN. i.e. let say PC1 and PC2 are in LAN. I want to know users available on PC2 through PC1 using **command prompt**.

Comment: Um........what?

Comment: @MDMarra If not clear with question downvote will not help I guess.

Comment: To All downvoters please let me know what is wrong with question so that I can correct.

Comment: Yummy Active Directory. Local accounts are for lusers. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PsExec from the Sysinternals suite (which you can download from `microsoft.com`) will let you run commands on a remote pc; in this case, `net user`.

Comment: Thax for your reply. net user will let me know users of pc where I run that command. I want to know other pc user

Comment: PsExec will let you run it on a remote computer from the one you are on.